# How to target a particular image from multiple images on a page in google plus post

Tags: google

I have multiple images on my page. But I want only one image to be displayed in the google post.

At present the post shows all the images on the page in the post in the form of slideshow.
Could you please provide a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean "in the google post"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean the image used in the +Snippet? If so, it can use schema.org and OpenGraph microdata to populate it, so for example you would use `itemprop="image"` on the image you want Google+ to use. https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/